# Android - Start an IntentService on a specific day/time each week

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot, intentservice

I'm working on an app that has an IntentService that shows a Notification with showtimes for a local venue. I want the IntentService to be called every Fri at 5am or at boot on Friday morning.

What would be the best way to do this?

Right now I'm thinking of having a parent IntentService that will start at each boot and check what day it is and run the child service accordingly, but I don't know how to deal with a scenario where the user doesn't reboot.

Also, how would I run just the IntentService at boot and not the entire GUI?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and use the [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method to set an Alarm that goes off every week at the same time.

Your booting requirement is probably not worth the effort, as very very few people reboot their mobile devices often. I've personally gone months without turning my phone off.

However, you don't need a parent service. You can do the checking of the day when the child service first starts up, and have it kill itself if its not Friday.

Comment: thanks. can you give me some pointers? i can find an alarmmanager example that i understand.   do i create the alarm in my main activity and have it call the service?